# Nunit Combinatorial throws TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, nunit

I have some test like this:

```
[Test, Combinatorial]
public void SomeTest(
        [Values(false, true)] bool flag,
        [Values(2, 5)] int someValue))
{
     var entity = new SomeClass();
     entity.Flag = flag;
     entity.SomeValue = someValue;
     var context = entity.GetContext();

     Assert.AreEqual(context.SomeValue, entity.SomeValue);
}
```

When I try to run test, it throws TargetParameterCountException. StackTrace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod(TestResult testResult)
at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)
```

What is wrong? I use Nunit 3.4.1and VS 2012. 
Simple tests work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and runs fine for me using the NUnit 3 Visual Studio Adapter. Based on the callstack, you are trying to run the code in an older NUnit 2 based adapter. It is either an older version of Resharper or an old version of the NUnit Visual Studio Extension from before it was updated to not run NUnit 3 tests.

Install the [NUnit 3 Visual Studio adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d) and give that a try. If you are using Resharper, you need to pay for an update.

Also, pro-tip, you don't need to include the values in the attribute for bool or enums, all values will be automatically injected. You also don't need the `Test` attribute.

Here is my simplified version of your example,

```
[Combinatorial]
public void SomeTest([Values] bool flag, [Values(2, 5)] int someValue)
{
    TestContext.WriteLine($"{flag} - ${someValue}");
}
```

And the results in the Visual Studio Adapter,

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found similiar decision. I tried to use NUnit 3.4 and got that problem. When I became to use NUnit 2.6 my test became to work fine.